# How can I upload a file on dropbox without using a dropbox SDK in Java?

Tags: java, dropbox

I know how to use dropbox API with dropbox core sdk:

```
dropboxClient.files().uploadBuilder("./").uploadAndFinish(inputStream);
```

But is there any possibilty to do so without using the sdk?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/How-to-get-a-Dropbox-Connection-in-Java-without-using-SDK/m-p/380504#M21252 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could roll your own methods and use the REST api they expose here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/overview